# Oraciones causales y el modo subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo

> (1) *Y como yo **permaneciera** en silencio*, él también continuó mudo y
>   inmóvil.
>
> (2) *Como no **volviese** para alimentar a su hijo*, su marido fue a
>   buscarla.

¿Me podríais por favor explicar por qué se usa el subjuntivo en estas dos oraciones causales? En ambas oraciones se refiere a algo que ya ha ocurrido y entonces se considera como algo ya conocido. Además la oración principal no es en forma negativa. Pues ¿por qué van con el subjuntivo?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece bastante que el uso del subjuntivo en este caso se debe a la sustitución con el *pretérito pluscuamperfecto*, que se usaba antiguamente.

Reemplazando quedaría:

> 1. *Y como yo **había permanecido** en silencio...*
> 2. *Como no **había vuelto** para...*